# How to animate something from point a to point b?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, jquery-animate

How can I use pure javascript to animate a picture from point a to point b. If not is there any frameworks I can use excluding jQuery? Here is what I have so far [http://jsfiddle.net/kmHZt/10/](http://bit.ly/YGAn2T)

Comment: jQuery is written in pure Javascript, so of course you can do it. The question is, how much work do you really want to do? And why not jQuery?

Comment: @GJK I guess because jQuery doesn't animate canvas elements, just DOM objects.

Comment: createjs is awesome for canvas development: http://www.createjs.com/#!/CreateJS

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of JavaScript and CSS transitions:

CSS:

```
.slide-elem {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s left;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s left;
    -o-transition: 0.5s left;
    transition: 0.5s left;
}
.slide-elem.triggered {
    left: 50px; // Your animation here
}
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector(".slide-elem").className += " triggered";
```

Of course, you can customize all this to do whatever you want.
More on CSS transitions: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alfred's answer you should also look at CSS animations (as opposed to transitions).

Here is a nice tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations

Css animations / transitions in conjunction with adding class names with javascript should be sufficient unless you are animating a lot of things, then I would recommend using [HTML 5 Canvas](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CE4QFjAA&url=http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp&ei=dRs4UerCMIyalQWiroCACw&usg=AFQjCNGf087N828N1tTcJCWSr6R5HgvXyg&sig2=L1v916Dm5xcmAm-fh08ZIg&bvm=bv.43287494,d.dGI)